# Akka HTTP: Credentials are not propagated to authenticateBasic method

Tags: scala, jwt, akka, akka-http

I have the following Akka directive structure

```scala
cors(){
   post {
      extractCredentials {
         credentials:Option[HttpCredentials] => {
            // I can successfully inspect the credentials here
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Now I am trying to use `authenticateBasic` like

```scala
private def foo(credentials: Credentials):Option[FineAuthenticationResult] = {
      credentials match
        case Credentials.Provided(token) =>
          println(token)
          Some(ValidCredentials("foo"))
        case _ => Some(InvalidToken("foo"))
}

cors(){
   post {
       authenticateBasic(
                  realm = "Secure",
                  foo
                ) { authenticationResult =>
                  // Keep track of authorization results per channel and EVENT type
                  val additionalTags = Map(
                    "eventType" -> event.customEventType,
                    "channel" -> event.channel
                  )
                  authenticationResult match
                    case InvalidToken(message) =>
                      reject(CredentialsRejection(s"invalid token $message", additionalTags))
                    case InvalidCredentials(message) =>
                      reject(CredentialsRejection(s"invalid token $message", additionalTags))
                    case ValidCredentials(_) => complete(StatusCode.int2StatusCode(200))
                }
   }
}
```

The `foo` authenticator always ends up in the Missing credentials case.
I am testing like

```scala
      Postman.post(uri = "/path/path",
        channel = Some("a_channel"),
        eventType = Some("a-request")) ~>
        addCredentials(getValidToken) ~>
        routes ~>
        check {
          status shouldBe StatusCodes.OK
        }
```

Why am I always getting missing credentials when using `authenticateBasic` while using `extractCredentials` always gives me the right credentials.

Comment: What does `getValidToken` do?

Answer (score 0):

**tldr**

The problem is really simple but I had to go through the internals of `authenticateBasic` to understand what is going wrong. We cannot use `authenticateBasic` with an `OAuth2Token`. We can only use `authenticateOAuth2`.

**More details**

`authenticateBasic` is using

```scala
  def authenticateBasicAsync[T](realm: String, authenticator: AsyncAuthenticator[T]): AuthenticationDirective[T] =
    extractExecutionContext.flatMap { implicit ec =>
      authenticateOrRejectWithChallenge[BasicHttpCredentials, T] { cred =>
        authenticator(Credentials(cred)).fast.map {
          case Some(t) => AuthenticationResult.success(t)
          case None    => AuthenticationResult.failWithChallenge(HttpChallenges.basic(realm))
        }
      }
    }
```

under the hood. And `authenticateBasicAsync` is using

```scala
  def authenticateOrRejectWithChallenge[C <: HttpCredentials: ClassTag, T](
    authenticator: Option[C] => Future[AuthenticationResult[T]]): AuthenticationDirective[T] =
    extractCredentialsAndAuthenticateOrRejectWithChallenge(extractCredentials.map(_ collect { case c: C => c }), authenticator)
```

Here we can see that `C` is in principle `BasicHttpCredentials`. But with `addCredentials` - in the case of `OAuth0` - `C` will be `OAuth0Token`. Consequently, this `collect`

```scala
_ collect { case c: C => c }
```

is going to drop the `Credentials` object.